# Kusto command to see all column names in table?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I don't find .show table details helpful, I would just like to see the name of every column in a kusto table

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [`getschema` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/getschemaoperator)

Answer (score 1):

```
TableName
| limit 1
```

You could see a 1 row sample of your table this way

Answer (score 0):

.show table [tableName] dimensions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).